# Are tag synonyms necessary?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I don't see the point of tag synonyms. I see bond for james-bond and nolan for Christopher-nolan. Wouldn't it make more sense to have a mod approve tags? We can even have people with enough rep do that by retagging. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a site as small as this, you *could* have a moderator approve all tags.  It would require co-ordination, and a governing tagging 'scheme' but there are only 3 moderators on this beta site.  This would start to break down if the number of people grew (more moderators or people with enough reputation).

On a larger site like StackOverflow or Super-User, with many more moderators this co-ordination would be unwieldy and I could see it breaking down.

The tagging mechanism (whilst not ideal) is a way of dealing with tagging without having to have significant co-ordination with other people.

Unfortunately we have to share the same platform with other sites that are significantly larger than we are.

Answer (score 8):

Tag synonyms are an easy way for us to associate tags that have different names but have the same meaning.  You list two excellent examples: [bond](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bond) and [james-bond](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-bond), and [nolan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nolan) and [christoper-nolan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christoper-nolan).

In these examples, we would make james-bond and christopher-nolan the parent tag because it's more descriptive and make bond and nolan a synonym.  What this does is it allows people to tag with either one, but end up in the same listing for clarity and cohesiveness.